# how can i order the category by date

Tags: loop

This may be a quick and simple fix for someone but i want to be able to sort by 'ASC' OR 'DESC'

This isn't my markup but here is the loop i want to change just not sure how. I read the query wordpress doc but couldn't figure out where to put '`ORDER' => 'ASC'`

Do i need to reset the WP QUERY? From what I read you only need to reset the query if you have multiple loops. Am I correct?

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <article class="post">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <h3 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="transicion"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <?php echo '<a href="', get_permalink(), '">';
                                            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                                the_post_thumbnail('blog_image', array('class' => "attachment-$size, imageborder img-responsive"));
                                            }
                                         echo '</a>'; 
                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <?php echo  excerpt(60); ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 col-sm-8">
                                        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <?php the_date(); ?> 
                                        <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> <?php the_category(', '); ?>.
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="pull-right">Read more &raquo;</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article> <!-- post -->
                <?php endwhile;?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <h2 class="post-title">No entries found</h2>
                <p>Not found anything that criteria. Try searching again or use the menu to navigate the site.</p>
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Search this site for "pre_get_posts" and "new wp_query"

Comment: Always reset **all** instances of `new WP_Query`, regardless. It is good practice and will save a ton of headaches later on

Answer (score 1):

When the instance of WP_Query is not a variable on the PHP file you are working on it tends to be the "main" query and to edit this instance of the WP_Query you will need to Hook to the `pre_get_posts` action and change what you need there. Here is an Exemple:

```
<?php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'q166401_pre_get_posts', 10, 1 );

/**
 * On this case I will filter only the Home and the main query
 * @param  WP_Query $query The query object
 */
function q166401_pre_query( $query ){
    // Stop this function when it's not Home or it's not the main query
    if ( ! $query->is_home() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }

    // Here you will set the filters you want
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
}
```

If you have any problems referrer to the [codex page related to this hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts).

Comment: i'll look into this monday thanks for the response at least. Will follow up on this @bordoni